# Can import external JavaScript Libraries in Grafana DataSource Library

Tags: javascript, datasource, grafana

I am having an issue trying to import crypto-js library in a Grafana Datasource Pluging I am developing.

I get the following exception:

> Error: (SystemJS) Cannot set property 'CryptoJS' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property 'CryptoJS' of undefined at Object.create.F (http://localhost:3000/public/plugins/grafana-my-datasource/external/crypto-js.js?bust=1493397621246:25:20) at execute (http://localhost:3000/public/plugins/grafana-my-datasource/external/crypto-js.js?bust=1493397621246:27:6) Error loading http://localhost:3000/public/plugins/grafana-my-datasource/module.js

I have this in the datasouce.js:

```
import _ from "lodash";

import moment from 'moment';

import CryptoJS from './external/crypto-js';

export class GenericDatasource {

.......
```

and in the Gruntfile.js:

```
externals: {
  cwd: 'src',
  expand: true,
  src: ['**/external/*'],
  dest: 'dist'
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The import looks correct. Is the path correct? Grafana looks in the dist directory when starting plugins. Is the path to the js file `./dist/external/crypto-js.js`?

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes the file crypt-js.js is located at ./dist/external/crypto-js.js

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

- Is Grafana finding the js file? Can you navigate to http://localhost:3000/public/plugins/grafana-my-datasource/external/crypto-js.js in your browser and get back a JavaScript file?
- Are you importing it correctly? Is CryptoJS the default import? You could try:

  - `import * as CryptoJS from './external/crypto-js';`
  - There is a [GitHub Issue here about ES6 and CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/55) which shows how to import just one algo.